# Go Logging does not appear

Tags: go, logging

I want to create a Dependency Injection for a logging system in golang,
but when I do `log.Info.Println` it doesn't print anything to the log file.
Here's my code:

app.go

```golang
package main

import (
    log "github.com/jass-trix/BVDI/backend/application/logging"
)

func main() {
    logger := log.InitLog()
    logger.Info.Println("test info")
    logger.Error.Println("test error")
}
```

init.go

```golang
package logging

import (
    "flag"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

const logPath = "log/path/"

//Logger is a struct that contain all type of logger
//logger will be separated into two level
type Logger struct {
    Info  *log.Logger
    Error *log.Logger
}

var infoLog *log.Logger
var errorLog *log.Logger

//InitLog is a function to instantiate logging
func InitLog() *Logger {

    flag.Parse()

    fileInfo, err := os.OpenFile(logPath+"file.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0660)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error on opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer fileInfo.Close()

    multiInfo := io.MultiWriter(fileInfo, os.Stdout)
    infoLog := log.New(multiInfo, "INFO: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)

    fileError, err := os.OpenFile(logPath+"file.error.log", os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_APPEND, 0660)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error on opening file: %v", err)
    }
    defer fileError.Close()

    multiError := io.MultiWriter(fileError, os.Stdout)
    errorLog := log.New(multiError, "ERROR: ", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    return &Logger{
        Info:  infoLog,
        Error: errorLog,
    }
}
```

When I call `logger.Info.Println()` in app.go it doesn't print anything,
but when I call `errorLog.Println()` in init.go it prints to the file.

Does logging support Dependency Injection?

Comment: You are closing both files at the end of InitLog. You cannot write to closed files.

Comment: Is it necessary to close file?

Answer (score 1):

In `InitLog` you used

> [defer](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#defer) fileInfo.Close()

It closed file after `InitLog` call. Then `logger.Info.Println("test info")` tries to write to the closed file.

If you (really) want to use global logger, you should not close file in `InitLog` function.

Comment: ah.. i see. Do we have to close the file or is it okay to leave it open ?

Comment: It's not OK, you should close it. Try to open file in your main func, pass it to ```InitLogger``` and add ```defer file.Close()``` statement there. Also I suggest you to use existing implementation of loggers (e.g. https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) instead of making it by yourself.

Comment: what will happen if i dont close the  file in the  long term?